# What gcc build reports are for?

Tags: gcc

http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/buildstat.html

I don't get what is the point of this posts and why I should be interested in those.

Someone could expand this concept a little more ?

Comment: Perhaps you should ask the GCC maintainers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Automated systems build gcc against the various target architectures and display error reports there after tests are run. It's just to show if any of the tests are failing, which might indicate that some recently-added code broke something.

Comment: and it's "normal" to show results without mentioning the configuration used to build this gcc releases ?

Comment: I don't know. The gcc devs would probably explain details if you asked.